# Initialising Issue

Tags: java, initialization

```
private void northroom()
{
    char choice2;
    boolean boolean_1 = false;
    String answer2;
    System.out.println("You press a panel next to the door");
    System.out.println("The panel lights up with a pinging sound");
    System.out.println("The door slowly scrapes open");
    System.out.println("You are now in North Room");
    System.out.println("There is a object in the coner of the room shoraded by darkness");
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Would you like to pick up object Yes(Y) or No(N)");
        while(boolean_1 == false)
        {

            answer2 = keyboard.next();
            choice2 = answer2.charAt(0);
            if(choice2 == 'Y')
            {
                System.out.println("You go pick up the object");
            }
            if(choice2 == 'N')
            {
                    System.out.println("Stare at object because you are useless");
                    System.out.println("Try again");
            }
        }
    } 
    while (**choice2** != 'Y' && **choice2** != 'N');
```

while (**choice2** != 'Y' && **choice2** != 'N');

Here both the choice2 are initialised how do I correct this so that it loops properly

Comment: I think you have an infinite loop in your nested `while` since `boolean_1` is never changed and there is no break statement. Not a solution, but just an observation.

Comment: Can you provide the code that makes the keyboard object?

Answer (score 1):

The compilers code-path analyzer doesn't go far enough to recognize that the `while(boolean_1 == false)` loop will always execute at least once.

As far as the compiler is concerned, the loop body might be skipped, in which case the `choice2` variable is unassigned, i.e. not *definitely assigned*.

You can fix that by initializing it to a dummy value, e.g.

```
char choice2 = ' ';
```

Of course, if the compiler did extended analysis, it would have found that the `while(boolean_1 == false)` loop runs forever, since `boolean_1` is never updated, and would have generated compile error saying that `while (choice2 != 'Y' && choice2 != 'N');` is *unreachable*.

Comment: Would this be due to the compiler changing `do-while` to a plain` while` in the background?

Comment: @LeviMuniz No, because the compiler is doing no such thing. Read my answer again. It is because the compiler believes the `while(boolean_1 == false)` loop *might* be **skipped**.

Comment: Alright, I didn't know how Java handled this exactly. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks making into a dummy value, fixed the problem and the rest of my code is now running smoothly

Comment: @BeepBoop You should accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer, so other people can see that the question has been answered to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the designed behavior for your nested loops. However, ur inner loop is a infinite loop. It can never end so outer loop can never check condition showed in last line of code